# Long gap in web developer tools timeline - What is it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

i am currently trying to optimize a website. I frequently experience a long gap in the loading of the page, where nothing seems to happen.

So i figured, i use the google chrome devtools timeline tool to analyze, what's going on.

This is, what it shows to me:

[image: google chrome devtools timeline analysis]

As you can see, between 2.27s and 3.97s there is nothing. Now i ask myself, what happens during that time? Why doesn't the tool show me anything during that time? Are there processes, which are not covered by the devtools timeline?

My suspicion is, that a video tag might be initalized during that time, because i have a video tag on the page, but i am not 100% sure, if that's the cause.

Has anbody come across such a gap as well and knows what the issue was then?

Comment: Remove the video tag and see if you still have the gap.

Comment: done, it really is the video tag. But how can i debug further, because there are other websites with a video tag, which run much faster.